# Climbing guide for the Yorkshire Dales

Tags: rock-climbing, uk, books

Can anybody reccommend a climbing guide for the Yorkshire Dales area? I'm off for a weekend trip there in a couple of months but I'm having difficulty finding a guide for the area. [Roughly the Askrigg region](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Askrigg/@54.3149665,-2.081093,11z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x487c1317144fcf35:0x17422ebb39ebece5)

Preferably this will include somewhere I can easily set up some top ropes on easy routes as I'm taking some inexperienced friends.

Barring a book, any recommendation's for crags that fit the bill, above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a good trawl though my local outdoors shop I came across this book:

[image]
[Yorkshire gritstone](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B009Q6EC8K/ref=s9_simh_gw_p14_d0_i1?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=148TEMRZMNA7YYA1HX0M&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=455344027&pf_rd_i=468294).

It covers an area called [slipstones](http://www.ukclimbing.com/logbook/crag.php?id=549), which appears to be the nearest significant crag.

Answer (score 5):

Another guide book option for you might be the BMC sport climbing guide.

[image]

http://www.bmcshop.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=5299

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the ROCKFAX? http://www.rockfax.com/climbing-guides/books/northern-england-2008/

[image]

By the way, this is a great site for finding info on crags in a given area: http://www.ukclimbing.com/logbook/map/ - once you find a crag it also lists relevant guidebooks.

Comment: ah! forgot about the ukclimbing logbook, good call!

Comment: Nothing on the logbook. :(